# Can't find partition tab in disk utility osX ver. 10.6.8

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I just got a used Mac Book Pro. I created a new admin account and deleted the old one as well as one other user. This is an older late 2007 MBP... the osX upgrade to 10.6.8 was just performed. My Macintosh HD is showing up as Partition 2.

I ran disk utility (not from install disk), but there was no partition tab. I have a 160GB drive with only 53GB of space left on it. Since I am the only user and have no files on the laptop yet, I don't understand why there is so little space left. Surely the OS can't use up over 100GB. I wanted to run disk utility to see if there were any recovery partitions or other partition left over from the previous owner that could be erased to make room for expanding the main partition. Unfortunately, there is no partition tab in disk utility. The documentation I have found on line states that this version of osX includes that utility.

The osX disks I have are for an older version so I wasn't sure if they would be of any use in solving this problem. Also, I was afraid if using the disks, would I lose the little bit of data/apps that I have assembled. I would rather not do a fresh install and have to do all the updates again to achieve this. The previous owner had some apps that I don't want to lose as I would have to pay handsomely to get them back.

Simply, if all the previous users data is backed up on here after deleting user is still taking up space on a recovery partition (that I can't see)... I need to locate it erase it and expand the primary partition to re-aquire disk space for my files.

I am new to Mac, so please be as descriptive as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Disk Utility, there is a column on the left with the HDD(s) and their partitions.
You might be looking at the "Macintosh HD" one, instead of the *name-of-HDD* one (where there is the Partition tab).

In order to see what is taking up all the space, I suggest you two apps:
[CleanMyMac 2](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) and [DaisyDisk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/).
The former will let you clean the system from everything unneeded; the latter, instead, will let you see where the huge (in size) data are.

After having located and deleted those unneeded files, you should consider a defragmentation with [iDefrag](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iDefrag.php), a disk-image (with Disk utility) and a second partition (based on that disk-image) for the times that you want to use certain apps. So you can do a fresh-install on the main partition.